# Showing Tool-tip & Cross-hair on two independent graphs from a single hover event?

Tags: highcharts

Good day,

We are trying to develop a report which contains two charts. Each chart shows different metrics on the same timescale (unix timestamp). The aim is to show the tooltip & cross hair on both charts regardless of which you hover over.

In my head I would like to get the xAxis timestamp (time) from the tooltip hover event on chart A. I would then fetch the associated series on chart B and trigger the tooltip refresh event.

As it stands, it looks like highcharts only accepts points.

I've added a mouseOver/Out event to both charts. This obtains the hoverPoints

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        $el.trigger('tooltip-open', {"$sourceEl": $el[0], "point": this});
                    },
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        $el.trigger('tooltip-close', {"$sourceEl": $el[0], "point": this});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

// Where $el is the highcharts container
// ..and tool-tip-XXXXX is a custom jQuery event.

My temporary work around is:
      $el.bind('tooltip-open', function (e, data) {
        var $el = $(this);

```
    if (data.$sourceEl.id == $el.id) {
        return;
    }

    var chart = $el.highcharts();

    var points = $(chart.series).map(function () {
        return this.points
    }).get();

    var pointsForTimestamp = $.grep(points, function (p) {
        return p.x == data.point.x;
    });

    $(pointsForTimestamp).each(function () {
        this.setState('hover');
    });

    chart.tooltip.refresh(pointsForTimestamp);
});

$el.bind('tooltip-close', function (e, data) {
    var $el = $(this);

    if (data.$sourceEl.id == this.id) {
        return;
    }

    var chart = $el.highcharts();

    chart.tooltip.hide();
});
```

var linkGraphs = function ($elA, $elB) {

```
function isEventHandled(data){

    data.count = data.count || 0;
    if(data.count > 0){
        return true
    }else{
        data.count++;
        return false;
    }
}

function bindToOpen($elA, $elB) {

    $elA.bind('tooltip-open', function (e, data) {

        if(!isEventHandled(data)){
            $elB.trigger('tooltip-open', data);
        }

    });
}

function bindToClose($elA, $elB) {

    $elA.bind('tooltip-close', function (e, data) {
        if(!isEventHandled(data)){
            $elB.trigger('tooltip-close', data);
        }
    });

}

bindToOpen($elA, $elB);
bindToOpen($elB, $elA);

bindToClose($elA, $elB);
bindToClose($elB, $elA);
```

};

Comment: Have you tried to use two panes in Highcharts? Like this [example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume)

Comment: On a quick note, my current work around to pull this off is:

Comment: @PawełFus We'd need to treat it as two separate but linked graphs. A unified legend wouldn't really work. That said you could potentially format it and fake the look and feel

Comment: Okay! Now, simple question, why you are using hoverPoints, while you have access to this.point - which is actually hovered point, so for example this.point.x will return timestamp for hovered point.

Comment: @PawełFus Agreed. I've updated the code now

Comment: Okay, so now what is the problem ?:)

Comment: @PawełFus This only provides a partial answer :(. It will only show the crosshairs where there are points in the same category. If not the bar will jump around. It also wont trigger outside of the point mousemove area

Comment: I think I need to see it live, so I could debug this - otherwise I can only guess. Create jsFiddle example, please.

Comment: @PawełFus Agreed. This is a little verbose so I'll try and clean it up later but for now: http://jsfiddle.net/milesburton/yN8BP/19/ << Hover outside of a point it wont match. Hover on a point where the linked chart doesn't have a value for that axis - it wont show the tooltip

Comment: Oh, now I see - but this won't show tooltip for non existing point. Highcharts doesn't provide any kind of approximation between points, only draw line/spline. You can display tooltip and crosshair only for points.

Comment: @PawełFus agreed. New Relic have managed to pull it off though. Unfortunately I'm out of time for this piece of work - I'll see if i can write a plugin